Perform operation in-place with xarray
I am going crazy over the following issue: I want to map values from an xarray data array. Since I am constrained on memory, I want to do that in-place, but it just won't work! The code works fine when I save everything in a temp array and assign corine_lc.values to that array. But I cannot do that, OOM will occur. Doing it in-place has no effect on the the original data!!
Can anyone point me to what the heck is going on in the code below?
The assertion fails and shows me that the mapping has not taken place. How can I get this to worK? Thank you so much!!
import rioxarray as rxr
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
CORINE_NA = -1000

corine_lc = rxr.open_rasterio('other_inputs/u2018_clc2018_v2020_20u1_raster100m/DATA/U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1.tif') 

vat_df = gpd.read_file('other_inputs/u2018_clc2018_v2020_20u1_raster100m/DATA/U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1.tif.vat.dbf')
vat_df['CODE_18'] = vat_df['CODE_18'].astype(np.int16)
value_to_class = dict(zip(vat_df['Value'], vat_df['CODE_18']))

data_shape = corine_lc.shape
xvals = corine_lc.coords['x'].values
yvals = corine_lc.coords['y'].values
chunk_size = 10000

# Iterate in chunks along the first axis, which is the y axis!
for start_idx in range(0, data_shape[1], chunk_size):
    end_idx = min(start_idx + chunk_size, data_shape[1])
    chunk = corine_lc.isel(y=slice(start_idx, end_idx)).values[0, :, :]
    # Map values using the dictionary
    flat_chunk = chunk.flatten()
    mapped_flat_chunk = np.fromiter((value_to_class.get(v, CORINE_NA) for v in flat_chunk), dtype=np.int16)
    mapped_chunk = mapped_flat_chunk.reshape(chunk.shape)

    # Assign mapped chunk back to dataset
    corine_lc.loc[dict(x=slice(xvals[0], xvals[-1]), y=slice(yvals[start_idx], yvals[end_idx-1]))] = mapped_chunk

# Verify that forest code is present
assert (corine_lc > 311).any(), "The values seem not to be in the expected range!"
return corine_lc


Work on a smaller problem, perhaps a subset of the current one. That will let you better understand which step(s) are memory hogs. You need to work on something small enough that it will succeed, so you can make measurements of consumed memory.
